# Bootstrap multiselect with fixed search input

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select

Is it possible to set the search input to be fixed in the Bootstrap Multiselect? I don't want to scroll also the search input with the selectable elements. I saw it is rendered as a list item (`<li>`), that's why is scrollable. I didn't found a configuration option which changes that behavior.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/myrluk3/a6hv0zvj/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do this with `css`, but it is a hack.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/myrluk3/a6hv0zvj/4/)